# PHP know if string contains part of another string

Tags: php

why this code below return false ?

```
strstr('/example/test', 'example/test/next');
```

The second parameter contains a good portion of the first parameter ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: because '/example/test' does not contain 'example/test/next'

Comment: And not only that, but 'example/test/next' does not contain '/example/test', either: even if you'd got the parameters the right way around, *neither* string contains the other string. (Also, if you only want to check if the string contains part of another string, you should be using strpos, like it says in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

the second parameter is what you search for, so you need to change the parameters around
and lose the first '/' in the second parameter.

```
echo(strstr('example/test/next', 'example/test'));
// Returns example/test/next
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong order of parameters... strstr('yourstring', 'searchstring') [strstr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php)

```
strstr('/example/test', 'example/test/next');
```

Cahge to

```
strstr('example/test/next', '/example/test');
```

--> it will return false too. bacause `'example/test/next'` has NO `'/'` at the begin..

```
strstr('/example/test/next', '/example/test');
```

--> will return '/example/test/next'

Comment: eventually, after enough edits you'll get to my answer